# Input form padding doesnt work in IE

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer

I am trying to add padding-right to an input so that I can place an image in that corner and not have the text flow behind it. It works fine in Chrome & Firefox but not in IE.

I have seen people recommend using float:left; but still it doesnt work.

### See the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/4zRRt/

Comment: If tested it locally on IE8 and IE9 and it works like a charm. Maybe it's some other problem, like a wrong base path? Could you place some more code or check the console in IE9 (hitting F12). Maybe it says, what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you want to do that (probably, I am guessing, the button image doesn't work for me obviously).

I am guessing you want an input with a nice submit button which is always on the right.

This is done with a parent relative element and the button who is absolute with a right offset of 10px (to accomedate for the extra space the shadow requires). And a top set to 0...

Here is a jsfiddle of that:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/4zRRt/10/

I put some extra `display:block;` in there to make the inputs block instead of inline, this will prevent other rendering problems too.

Comment: Thank you looks good, but there still seems to be the problem of the text going behind that image in IE, why is that?

Comment: Has something to do with overflow in inputs... been there, better off not depending on the input for styling too much... Hang on, cooking something up.

Comment: Updated the answer to include a link to a sample where I kinda cheated a bit by using the form element for styling and made the input invisible/low profile so it only encompasses the height/width of where text may be. I don't think you're going to get it to work easily with the padding on the input itself.

Comment: Thank you, that is a much better way to do it. Thanks for your time :)